# Static files are not getting loaded in Django

Tags: python, django, deployment, django-staticfiles, whitenoise

Static files are not getting loaded when running on server.  I have tried the whitenoise library and referred to the Documentation (http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html) as well, but no luck. I am new to Django, would appreciate any help.
PS: I have also collected the static folder using-

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Below is what I have in my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_celery_beat',
    'django_extensions',
    'haystack',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'django_db_logger.apps.DbLoggerAppConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'server.wsgi.application'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

Answer (score 1):

If static files are loading when you run locally, but not on your server, you may need to add something to your web server config.  E.g. for nginx and your static folder location:

```
location /static/ {
    root /home/user/testing;
}

location /media/ {
    root /home/user/testing;
}
```

More details and an example for Apache at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Comment: Thanks Mark. Yes, the issue is only on the server. I just tried add this, but no luck yet. My static folder is /home/user/testing/static/

Comment: Which web server are you using?

Comment: I am using nginx

Comment: I have edited my answer to use your static folder location.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify in `Project/urls.py` file

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
]

# For static file and media
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, if your `STATIC_URL` is defined as `static/`, you can do this by adding the following snippet to your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```